# random number from 0-100 opposite numbers in the upper triangle and the one tringle in symmetrical matrix

Tags: python, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I made the NxN matrix with Zeros and Ones and symmetrical and diagonal = 0. Now I want to make another matrix. Instead of the one in the matrix, I put a random number from 0-100 opposite numbers in the upper triangle and the one tringle have the same value as in the picture
and I want to do this to all ones in the new matrix
Thank You
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXZE7.png)

Comment: Can you post the code that you've used to generate this, and could you post the expected output as text?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is generate an NxN array of random numbers and multiply:

```
import numpy as np

N = 7
base = np.zeros((N,N))
for _ in range(15):
    a = np.random.randint(N)
    b = np.random.randint(N)
    if a != b:
        base[a,b] = 1
        base[b,a] = 1

print(base)

# Fetch the location of the 1s.
ones = np.argwhere(base==1)
ones = ones[ones[:,0] < ones[:,1],:]

# Assign random values.
for a,b in ones:
    base[a,b] = base[b,a] = np.random.randint(100)

print(base)
```

Note that my array creation is just for this example.  You said you already have the 1/0 matrix so I'm not worried about that part.

Output:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]]
[[ 0. 37.  0.  7. 43. 40. 54.]
 [37.  0. 45.  0. 87. 40.  0.]
 [ 0. 45.  0. 74.  8.  0.  0.]
 [ 7.  0. 74.  0. 47.  0. 75.]
 [43. 87.  8. 47.  0.  0. 41.]
 [40. 40.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [54.  0.  0. 75. 41.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks but the upper ones that reflects the lower ones don't have the same values

Comment: They don't in your sample, either.

Comment: this is actually my problem I need to make them have the same value.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer.